# Is there any open bugs list for IBM MQ?

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm interested in bugs list fo IBM MQ, but I have found only [Fix packs](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27043086) with list of resolved [APARs](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21424131).
 
Is there any open bugs list(APARs) for IBM MQ or I can view only resolved issues?

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 0):

Individual APAR pages are available once IBM support finalizes the fix. These are searchable via ibm.com, google or any other internet search engine. Each APAR page list target fixpacks for the versions they will be fixed in.   The APAR will only show up on a specific version's fixlist when that version's fixpack that contains the APAR is released.